# Why does my form keep sending if it doesn't meet the condition?

Tags: javascript, forms, save

I have a button where I erased the type="submit"

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="save-form"
  >Save</button>
```

and I added an Onclick function in javascript

```
        $('#save-form').on('click', function (){
            let placesArrayEmpty = checkPlacesArrayEmpty();
            if (placesArrayEmpty){
                $('#alert-empty').show();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#alert-empty').hide();
                }, 6000);
            }else{
                $("#place-form").submit();
            }
        });
```

this "prevent" saving the form if an input is empty, the verification is done, the if(placesArrayEmpty) is true, even the change of "empty" is shown, after being shown, immediately the form is sent, I don't understand why

Comment: A form has a [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) try using it instead of the button click.

Answer (score 2):

Your submit button submits the form even if your JavaScript that runs when the submit button is clicked doesn't **also** submit the form.

Don't use a click event on the button. Use a submit event on the form.

If the form shouldn't be submitted, prevent the default behaviour.

```
$("selector for your form").on("submit", function (event) {
    if (there are problems) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, if I return false, the form doesn't send

```
           $('#save-form').on('click', function (){
                let placesArrayEmpty = checkPlacesArrayEmpty();
                if (placesArrayEmpty){
                    $('#alert-empty').show();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#alert-empty').hide();
                    }, 6000);
                    return false;
                }else{
                    $("#place-form").submit();
                }
            });
```